# VB.Net UserPrincipal is Nothing if using Azure AD

Tags: vb.net, azure-active-directory, userprincipal

We have a winform application and in order to login, we are trying to get the currently logged in user using UserPrincipal.Current

When the currently logged in user is an Azure AD account, the UserPrincipal is Nothing.

- Is there a way to get the currently logged in user when using Azure AD ?

Code used:

```
Dim currentWinUser As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current
```

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into the answers? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Microsoft Graph API to get the logged in user

See reference here: [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

You need an access token to call Microsoft Graph API. See Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0).

A sample may be helpful [here](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/12/using-the-graphclient-sdk-in-a-vb-net-console-application/).

Comment: Using Graph requires .Net Framework 4.7, we are on 4.6 at the moment. I will give it a go and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @mrc Not sure if Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library applies to VB.net. But it targets .Net Framework 4.6.1. See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet#microsoft-graph-net-client-library.

Comment: When I tried it, it sent a message saying that it isn't compatible. But I will try it again and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it using the Azure CLI:

```
az ad signed-in-user show --query objectId -o tsv
```

As Alan mentioned Graph API is a good way to go though.

User.Identity.Name will also give you the info for the logged in on-prem Active Directory user.